# RecyclerView never focus on the last element

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to set the last element of recyclerview fully visible to the user whenever it takes a photo.

So I used recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(recycler.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);

But I **always** see the penultimate photo. Even if I change "- 1" to "+ 1" or "+ 4" or even "+ 15"

My recyclerView first scrolls to the last element and then add a new element to my array. So this way, it never really goes to the last element. It should be the opposite.

Could anyone help, please? Am I missing something?

```
if (success) {
                File mFile = new File(mDir, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + ".jpg");

                mImageCapture.takePicture(mFile,
                        new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                                mListOfPhotos.add(file.getAbsolutePath());

                                mAdapter.setmListOfPhotos(mListOfPhotos);
                                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                                actualNumberOfPhoto();

                                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError imageCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                                String mMessage = "Photo capture failed: " + message;
                                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, mMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                assert cause != null;
                                cause.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
            }
```

EDIT:

Code into actualNumberOfPhoto()

```
    private void actualNumberOfPhoto(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mNumberOfPhotoTV.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.minPhotos, mListOfPhotos.size()));

        mIDDemande = mSharedPreferences.getInt(ConstantsClass.EXTRA_ID_APPLICATION, 0);

        if (mIDDemande != 0) {
            if (mListOfPhotos.size() > 0) {
                mSendPhotoFAB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (mListOfPhotos.size() < 1) {
                mSendPhotoFAB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else if (mListOfPhotos.size() >= 6) {
            mSendPhotoFAB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (mListOfPhotos.size() < 6) {
            mSendPhotoFAB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: call your smoothScroll method below notifyDataSetChanged method.

Comment: What you have done in `actualNumberOfPhoto(mRecyclerView);`

Comment: What this method do `mAdapter.setmListOfPhotos()`?

Comment: @PratikButani It sets my array to my Adapter, the array my recycler view needs.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be like this:

```
@Override
public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
    mListOfPhotos.add(file.getAbsolutePath());

    mAdapter.setmListOfPhotos(mListOfPhotos);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mListOfPhotos.size());

    //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I feel like my recycler view first scrolls to the last element and then add a new element to my array. So this way, it never really goes to the last element. It should be the opposite.